# Managing Windows Though QT Application in Linux (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I've been making a simple application which is able to launch a variety of other applications through QT5 (using QProcess class) but I've been running into a few key issues with the design. Specifically, it seems that Qprocess cannot set focus to windows that have been created via QProcess' start() function. This means that once a user opens more than one window, it can never return to the previous window that has been opened. After looking further into this dilemma, it has become clear that my program will need to be able to handle basic window management in order to fulfill my specifications.

I've decided that the best example to study for my program is Docky, which is capable of opening, closing and switching windows. Looking at the source code for that project was helpful, but there were many C# system calls that were used for fetching the list of client-windows which aren't available for my C++ program.

How can I get a list of all the X11 Windows that the client is running and provide basic window management (Switch To/ Open / Close Window) using C++? Is there a cross platform way of doing this through QT? Can I get this information directly using XServer?

Comment: Could this post be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014822/how-to-know-which-window-has-focus-and-how-to-change-it

Comment: I definitely think it helps, but I have heard that there's a preference to use XCB over XLib. Can't say I know exactly why though, so I'll do some research on this tomorrow.